# Добавление новых точек в Surface plot и формирование нового графика

Tags: python, matplotlib

Имеется некий 3D график, задаваемый координатной прямоугольной сеткой и значениями в узлах сетки. Так же имеется набор отдельных точек, заданных трехмерными координатами.

Как возможно сформировать новый график, объединив точки и исходный график?

***Пример кода:***

```
    x = np.arange(100, 200 + 1, 5)
    y = np.arange(750, max(x) * 3 + 1, 1)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)  # сетка

    _size = self.X.shape
    Z = np.zeros(shape=(_size[0], ._size[1]))

    # формирование значений исходного графика
    for ind_x, i in np.ndenumerate(X[0]):
         for ind_y, j in np.ndenumerate(Y[:, 0]):
               val = np.random.randint(-85, -80) # получение значений
               Z[ind_y][ind_x] = val # запись значений

    # получение значений некоторых специфичных точек
    x1 = 156
    y1 = 1003
    z1 = -50

    # после чего необходимо добавить эти точки в исходный график
    ...

    # и построить новый график
    plt.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

Comment: Можно больше исходных данных? О каком графике речь? Scatter  или surface? В исходном графике координатная сетка - 2d + значения как третья координата? Если так, то что мешает вывести исходный график + новый на одном и том же axes?

Comment: Добавил пример кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас в приведенном коде ошибки - я уже не говорю про .self и ._size[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBuB0.png) - будем считать это неаккуратным копированием - у вас np.arange неверно инициализируются при заданных условиях:

```
y = np.arange(750, max(x) * 3 + 1, 1)
#при max(x)*3 == 600 - шаг должен быть отрицательным
```

Во-вторых, чтобы новые точки стали **частью поверхности**, их координаты должны попасть в матрицу координат, которую вы получаете с помощью `np.meshgrid(x, y)`. То есть, фактически, нужно заново генерировать матрицу из векторов, к которым вы добавили новые точки.

Если же нужно просто отобразить новые точки на 3d-графике с имеющейся поверхностью, то воспользуйтесь `ax.scatter(x,y,z)`. К примеру, так (добавленная точка выделена красным):

```
x1 = 150
y1 = 700
z1 = -84

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_zlim(-120,-40)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=.2)
ax.scatter(x1,y1,z1, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: sample3]

Comment: Благодарю, именно это и хотел услышать. 

// Ошибки в приведенном коде - действительно неаккуратный перенос.